# Несколько тип пользователей в django?

Tags: django

Возможно ли в django создать несколько тип  пользователей ( каждый  со своей auth) ? Например клиенты, менеджеры, админы ?

Comment: А зачем, что мешает просто добавить поле с ролью к уже имеющимся пользователям?

Comment: Трогать стандартную модель `User` крайне нежелательно. Обычно в таких случаях создают вторую модель (`Profile`), связывают её с моделью пользователя через `OneToOneField`, добавляют необходимые поля и пишут логику обработки.

Comment: А расширение abstractbaseuser ?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно. Тогда вам придётся расширить **AbstractBaseUser**, как упомянул [@RouslanKartoev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/361104/rouslan-kartoev) или воспользоваться предложением [@nomnoms12](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/339283/nomnoms12). В любом случае для разных типов пользователей можно кастомизировать авторизацию с помощью написания своих бэкендов авторизации. Это описано в документации:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend